# C# ASP.NET MVC jQuery .html() function not working with DevExpress chart data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, devexpress

Hello fellow developers,

I have a problem with my ajax calls, after succesfully retrieving data from my Action, the jQuery html() function does not correctly replace the html with the updated html content (the content is a DevExpress chart based on a partialView with only the chart in it.

The script worked perfectly, but suddenly during development the charts wouldn't update anymore. Here is my code.

**Changes.cshtml**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSelectTimescale(s, e){
        var chartname = s.uniqueID.split("TimescaleMenu").join("");
        var actionname = chartname + "PartialChart";
        var url = "/Home/" + actionname + "/";
        var container = actionname + "Container";
        var chartContainer = actionname + "_IMG";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: { timescale: e.item.name },
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log(chartname);
                console.log(actionname);
                console.log(url);
                console.log(container);
                console.log(chartContainer);

                LoadingPanel.ShowInElementByID(chartContainer);
            },
            success: function (response) {
                LoadingPanel.Hide();
                $(container).html(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

    <div id="AnimalChangedByPartialChartContainer">
    <div id="AnimalChangedByPartialChart" onmousemove="ASPx.chartMouseMove(event, &#39;AnimalChangedByPartialChart&#39;)" onclick="ASPx.chartClick(event, &#39;AnimalChangedByPartialChart&#39;)" style="height:300px;width:500px;">
    <img id="AnimalChangedByPartialChart_IMG" src="/DXB.axd?DXCache=eb3eda3a-8a56-485e-a825-715239856987" alt="The ANIMAL_HISTORY chart showing XML inlees module (PDA2RUMA) series, CRV RsReproduction series, LNV Verblijfplaatsen ophalen series, LNV Verblijfplaatsen correctie  series." />
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The request url is correct, I've tested it and in the network console I can see the image of the generated chart based on the newly selected timescale.

"LoadingPanel.Hide();" is the last line of code that properly executes. 
Does anyone know why
    $container.html(response); 
does not properly replace my current element?

Comment: Can you check your browser console? I'm going to assume it is looking at the container as an HTML element and not an Id.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need to set the **dataType** attribute to the ajax request since it doesn't know what type of data to expect. [dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)